# Delete column in a table azure mobile app

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Table already had Delete column for soft delete from web application.

Same table I have pointed to azure mobile services/app.

Also created DeleteMS column for mobile services and used auto mapper in **WebApiConfig.cs**.

While creating DTO, I rename old Delete column to IsDelete and kept as it is EntityData-Delete property.

**Contactdto**

```
public class Contactdto : EntityData
{
    public int contact_id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    //public bool DeletedMS { get; set; }   //manually added column
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
cfg.CreateMap&lt;tblcontact, Contactdto&gt;()
.ForMember(dto => dto.IsDeleted, map => map.MapFrom(tbl => tbl.deleted));

cfg.CreateMap&lt;Contactdto, tblcontact&gt;()
.ForMember(tbl => tbl.DeletedMS, map => map.MapFrom(dto => dto.Deleted));
```

Is this a right approach? or shall I use same column already we had?
Once record is deleted from mobile app. Will it affect in Web Application after sync service run?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already implemented soft delete in your web app, it's easiest to just use that exact same column in your Mobile App backend. The only way a record will be marked as deleted is when there is a DELETE call, either through the /tables endpoint or the mobile client.

Also, make sure you are using Mobile Apps, as that is the latest version of the service. See [What are Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop/).